# Find room required for lectures

Tags: c, interview-questions

I have implemented a code to resolve following interview question. Please advice how it can be improved folks. Thanks in advance.

> Given an array of time intervals (start, end) for classroom lectures
> (possibly overlapping), find the minimum number of rooms required.
>
> For example, given [(30, 75), (0, 50), (60, 150)], you should return
> 2.

I have just printed output value without proper self checking method due to my time limitation for this task. `coll_max`, `coll_min` are used to define time range of fully occupied rooms at each loop, thus requiring new room. Again, pardon my English here xD.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int get_max(int arr[])
{
    if (!arr)
        return -1;
    if (arr[0] > arr[1])
        return arr[0];
    else
        return arr[1];
}

int get_min(int arr[])
{
    if (!arr)
        return -1;
    if (arr[0] < arr[1])
        return arr[0];
    else
        return arr[1];
}

unsigned int get_room_number(int arr[][2], unsigned int subjNo)
{
    /* colliding range, each time class time collide with those values,
    we increase neccRoom counter */
    int coll_max = INT_MAX;
    int coll_min = INT_MIN;

    int min;
    int max;
    unsigned int neccRoom = 0;  //neccarry rooms

    for (int i = 0; i < subjNo; i++)
    {
        min = get_min(arr[i]);
        max = get_max(arr[i]);

        if (min < 0 || max < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (min <= coll_max && max >= coll_min)
        {
            neccRoom++;
            if (min > coll_min) {
                coll_max = min;
            }
            if (max < coll_max) {
                coll_max = min;
            }
        }
    }

    return neccRoom;
}

int main(void)
{
    int list[][2] = {
            { 30, 75 },
        { 0, 50 },
        { 60, 150 }
    };

    int answer = get_room_number(list, 3);

    if (answer > 0)
        printf("neccessary rooms: %u\n", answer);
    else
        printf("input array ERROR\n");

}
```

Comment: Although this may work for 3 lectures, it does not handle the general case for `n` rooms to find an optimal minimum.